# How can I find the version of the OS by regular expressions?

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I'm trying to get the version of RHEL and echo a message if its higher than or equal to RHEL 7.0. I want to use regular expressions.

```
str=$(cat /etc/redhat-release)
if [[ "$str" =~ .*release\s+7.* ]]; then
echo "Compatible OS"
fi
```

The output of the cat /etc/redhat-release is :

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.0 (Maipo)
```

but i can't get the pattern to match and echo the success message. It works if the regexp I use is `.*7.*` but not with `.*release\s+7.`

Comment: Replace `\s+` with `[[:space:]]*` or [`[[:blank:]]*`](https://ideone.com/v5gKlz).

Comment: You can also use an escaped space character `\ ` in this particular case.